# How strictly are "universal design" standards enforced in open data?

Tags: usa, best-practice

["Universal design"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_design)is a U.S. government standard that forces items, in this case metadata, to be accessible to people with disabilities.

Apparently universal design standards were promulgated some years ago (2011?), but aren't in yet in followed everywhere, even today.

Why is that? How strictly are universal design standards enforced in and outside of open data? Could it be the case that they are, in fact, enforced across open data, and the issue exists only outside the open data system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u.s. government doesn't even enforce section 508. universal design is just another idea to them. i have yet to see anyone doing it or enforcing it.